# How to deal with inserts and duplicates without an unique ID

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm dealing with a record transfer problem in the database. I have a `TableA` which contains raw data (the closest thing to unique identifiers are a timestamp and an `IDENTITY (1,1)` I created before) and `TableB` which is the same data but processed with a stored procedure which in some cases will duplicate records by the nature of the data we are dealing with (so same ID's for split records and so on).

The user expects to run the stored procedure each time after he "bulk" inserts new data into `TableA` from a file that gets updated so the process will be something like:

`... > USER INSERTS INTO TableA > USER RUNS STORED PROCEDURE > PROCEDURES INSERTS INTO TableB > REPEAT`

My problem is when running the stored procedure it will run on `TableA` x amount of times and obviously add the same data over and over and increasing the ID value, I was thinking of using a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` but again, I have no unique ID after running the procedure. Cleaning `TableB` and refilling is not reliable because of the size of the DB, also I need to avoid triggers for the same reason.

What could be the cleanest and pragmatic approach?

Comment: TableA sounds like a *staging* table, and that it should be emptied or recreated after every bulk insert of new data. If you need to support concurrency (e.g. two users inserting their own bulk data at the same time), you can either have each user use their own #temp table instead, or create a single table with an additional column indicating the user.

Comment: Hey @AaronBertrand, I was checking out with the boss your suggestion and overwriting the table or using #temp tables it's not viable as my area it's not the only using `TableA`. He told me grab the last (newest) timestamp from `TableB` and process `TableA` from that date on. You have any idea if that's even possible?. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand has the right idea, what you are doing with multiple users/areas sounds very messy.

Comment: That depends. Does each _batch_ of records get the same timestamp, or does each _row_ get it's own timestamp? If it's the first case, you probably have a reasonable, although not guaranteed, batch identifier. If it's the second, timestamps between batches started close to each other will overlap.

Comment: But with that said, a better model would still be to use #temp tables for each user insert, add a legitimate batch_ID to those records, add them to `TableA`, then process them through to `TableB`, thereby insuring the integrity of both tables.

Comment: @Dugggie It is, thats how the DB it's made, tried to create a requirement for the DBA to append ID's for records but these ID's store confidential data from other systems so I can't work with that either.

Comment: @EricBrandt Some users upload these records to a SAP-ish software, sometimes bulked from a CSV so these timestamps will be the same for those cases, if introduced manually it will have a "more" specific timestamp, but they aren't unique for most of them, in fact I tried a `checksum` as ID but still, they won't be unique if for x record is duplicated with the variables I'm using. Considering the newest timestamp can be more helpful but I have no clue working it out.

Comment: Hi @Ali, does the data in TableA need to be retained after it is moved to TableB ? If not, then as others have suggested, temp tables are the way to go. If it does need to be retained then finding a workable solution is not going to be easy. If multiple people are using this at the same time, I can't see how you will do it without temp tables or adding some other identifier as others have said, a user_id or batch_id for example.

Comment: Hello @Dugggie, `TableA` and `B` need to be retained, it's historic for many areas, and for mine I have to work with the CTE I created and then join other table to `TableB`, more changes on TableA will affect the results for other areas. I know it's not easy, been thinking about it for weeks, hope business rules were more flexible but this is what we have...

Comment: What about a database trigger @Ali ? When the data is added to TableA, you could use a trigger to run a stored procedure and insert it into TableB automatically. This could be done for all users for every record. Perhaps not the most efficient in DB terms but it would work.

Comment: @Dugggie I was urged to not use triggers, I could solve the problem long time ago but the db it's already "chunky" in every way to be honest. The closest solution could be storing the `MAX(timestamp)` from `TableB` and execute the stored procedure on `TableA` where that criteria is greater than itself (?), but I don't know if its possible.

Comment: Hi @Ali, I suspected as much. What you are saying would probably be OK provided you could be certain that only 1 batch of updates at a time is being processed. If you had 2 or more users uploading and processing data I think you would run into trouble. In terms of how to achieve it, you would probably be able to get the MAX date from TableB as part of the stored procedure you are using to load data into TableB from TableA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely not a perfect solution, but it's an answer to the question posed about how to process data in `TableA` for `datetimes` that are greater than the most recent value in `TableB`.

The pattern that would usually be applied here would be to structure the stored procedure that's processing `TableA` data with something like this.

```
SET ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;

DECLARE @LastTimestamp DATETIME;

BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION

  SELECT 
    @LastTimestamp = MAX(TimestampColumn) 
  FROM 
    TableB;

  INSERT #StagingTable
    <ColumnList>
  SELECT
    <ColumnList>
  FROM
    TableA
  WHERE 
    TimestampColumn > @LastTimestamp;

  <Stored procedure magic, performed on #StagingTable....>

  INSERT TableB
    <ColumnList>
  SELECT
    <ColumnList>
  FROM
    #StagingTable;

  COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
  <Other Error Handling>

END CATCH;
```

Anything you can do to insure that `INSERT`s into `TableA` have explicit transactions declared will be helpful, but by using the `REPEATABLE READ` [Isolation Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql), you'll get *some* protection from `INSERT`s happening close together.

It also might be worth your time to look into [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server) and [Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server) to see if one of them might offer you some assistance.

Comment: Had to tweak a bit the code to make it work on my table but it accomplished the task, thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped.